# Is javap missing some line numbers?

Tags: java, bytecode, javap

If I compile the following source code:

```
1.  public class Example {
2.    public boolean foo(boolean a, boolean b, char ch) {
3.      if (a && Character.isLetter(ch)
4.            || b && Character.isDigit(ch)
5.            || !a && !b) {
6.        return true;
7.      }
8.      return false;
9.    }
10. }
```

with Java-7 (either OpenJDK or Oracle) I get the following LineNumberTable:

```
line 3: 0
line 6: 30
line 8: 32
```

However, compiling the same source code with Java 8 (either OpenJDK or Oracle) I get another LineNumberTable:

```
line 3: 0
line 4: 16
line 6: 30
line 8: 32
```

Why does the LineNumberTable returned by Java 7 not include lines 4 and 5?

And why does the LineNumberTable returned by Java 8 not include line 5?

Comment: may be java-8 is just add more message for debug? the LineNumberTable is for debuger to connect bytecode with source code.

Comment: yes, for debuggers and many other purposes like for example, coverage tools like JaCoCo/Eclemma which relies on bytecode. actually, Eclipse does not use Javac to compile Java files (instead it uses an internal compiler), and the bytecode (i.e., LineNumberTable) of the above code includes all numbers (3,4,5,6,8).

Comment: You've clearly demonstrated javac omits those line numbers.  Why do you expect those lines to be present, though?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, it isn’t exactly specified, how many hints compilers should include. It’s always a trade-off between usefulness and resulting code size. In the worst case, you would have a several byte length information for each single-byte instruction. Also, certain language constructs may generate instructions spread over different byte code locations, whereas others do not not map to byte code instructions at all.

The strategy of previous `javac` implementations was simple. Unlike Eclipse, it doesn’t generate line number information for *expressions*, but only for *statements*. So a single statement may span multiple source code lines but its entire code gets associated with the statement’s first line only.

Apparently, this strategy has been changed to make an exception to this rule when there are embedded method invocations. So for method invocations, there will be a line number information, but not for other expressions.

You may verify this by playing around with multi-line statements deliberately adding or removing nested invocations. E.g., the following code

```
static int test(int a, int b, int c, int d) {
    return
            a
           +b
           +c
           +d;
}
```

will report only a single line number, the one bearing the `return` keyword. Now change the code to

```
static int test(int a, int b, int c, int d) {
    return
            a
           +b
           +c+test(a,b,c,d)
           +d;
}
```

and the line number table will have two entries, the one of the `return` keyword and the one of the nested method invocation. You may move the invocation to a different line or even adding another invocation, e.g.

```
static int test(int a, int b, int c, int d) {
    return
            a
           +b+test(a,b,c,d)
           +c
           +d+test(a,b,c,d);
}
```

and the line number table will support my guess about `javac`’s new strategy.